# How to use sx:autocomplter in Struts2 for AJAX purpose?

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-autocompleter-example/) tutorial to build AJAX into Struts2:

I successfully reached the final step and I have exactly the same interface shown as the user does, also, my first dropdown box has AJAX working perfectly, however, the second dropdown won't have any AJAX working at all.

The difference between the first dropdown and second one is how they utilize the list of items. The first dropdown uses:

```
<sx:autocompleter list="{'1','12','13'}"
```

To hard-coded the list of items, while the second one uses the following way:

```
<sx:autocompleter list="webframeworks"
```

This is actually where I am getting confused, how does struts2 manage to know webframeworks is a field within AutoCompleterAction class and retrieve the value of the list?

There are two oberservations:One thing I notice is that the "webframeworks" is also the field name in AutoCompleterAction class. The second is that the first dropdown menu is actually populated, whilst the second one is empty.

I am just a beginner, thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: Your first observation is right...Struts does it internally because names are same.

Comment: if you have just started with S2 do not use DOJO tags as they are no longer supported

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, then what is the alternative now to do AJAX in Struts2, or there is little need to do AJAX in struts2?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Struts 2 does support DOJO..its just that it does't come inbuilt.

Comment: @Kevin you can make AJAX call with Struts 2. And you can use any JS library like DOJO, JQUERY etc..

Comment: @rai.skumar: tags being used by OP are deprecated DOJO plugin which is no longer being supported by team.OP is free to use Ajax with simple  DOJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @UmeshAwasthi pointed out, integrated Dojo with Struts2 is deprecated since 2.1.x version.

This mainly because integrated Dojo was older than official Dojo version, less mantained, buggy etc.

You can use out-of-the-box Dojo, jQuery or any other AJAX Framework to do the job, BUT I strongly recommend you to take a look at the [Struts2-jQuery Plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action), that is a complete, well written an mantained library that will allow you to achieve almost every kind of result without the need to learn jQuery alone.

Just click on the Widget menu of the showcase, then on Autocompleter, and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In second example data is coming from the action class on server.

```
  List<String> webframeworks = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Above list is getting populated in the action class. So in second case you are referring to the list with name **webframeworks** .

Also as you asked how does it know; you are using STRUTS 2 tag (<**sx:autocompleter** ..) so Struts takes care of it internally.

Comment: get it:). Then could you suggest why my second list isn't populated at all?

Comment: Example is using dojo library for auto completion and ajax call...debug ajax call part if rest is fine.